# LXD 2.0 Local Networking

Tags: lxc, lxd

Today I apt-get upgraded my machine (14.04) and now I can no longer access any of my local LXD containers.

There was a message warning that I needed to reconfigure the container networking but now I can't find any reference to it on-line.

Does anyone know of a step by step guide to networking in LXD 2.0?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/cronnelly/98345100afe21840267270da3283b371

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `dpkg-reconfigure lxd` and set up IPv4 and/or IPv6 networks.

Comment: Useful article about LXD 2.0 networking: https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/07/lxd-networking-lxdbr0-explained/